# Photoshop Layer Selection larger than object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize

New designer here,
I'm having trouble with a certain layer in Photoshop CS6.
The image "transform controls" or the resizing box around the layer/ Selected area is much larger than the object while there is nothing there.

How can I Make the resizing box smaller without shrinking the image.

I've provided a screenshot

[image]

Comment: There must be something there. It could be totally invisible, but there must be something there. One way to get rid of the extras would be to either do a selection with Lasso tool **or** `Select > All`and then `Layer > New > Layer via cut` and now you have a new layer that, at the very least, can't be larger than the document. You can then delete the old layer. If it's not a raster layer, you should probably delete the extras from within the container, what ever it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the **contents** of the layer are actually larger than your *visible* canvas.

If you want to **delete** the content outside the visible canvas...

- Choose `Select > All`
- then choose `Image > Crop`

This will delete all the layer contents outside the canvas area.

If you **do not** want to delete the extra area, you can add a **Layer Mask** so that only the portion you want visible is seen in the mask. Then convert the layer (with the mask) to a **Smart Object**. Your transform handles will then match the size of the mask, rather than it's hidden contents.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything that will make the selection box smaller, but if you switch to the move tool and then try to move those items, you will see that the selection box contracts to the edges of the items you are moving.

If you want to resize the selection box itself, go to the Select menu and choose "transform selection" (I think that is the name of the command. I am responding from my iPad and can't check in photoshop to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

you can select the image and then select the trim option from the edit menu . It will remove the empty areas selected.

Comment: sorry its Image menu

Answer (score -1):

I think this site may helpful.
 http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/transform-selection/